# Synchronizing/transferring contacts from phone to app

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I wanted to enable my app user to send messages to their existing phone contacts. There are a few good tutorials, like [this one](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/). My problem is that the loading time depends on the number of contacts in the phone, and about 300 contacts take about 10 secs to load.

So the question would be what is the best way to synchronize app and phone contacts, so that I don't have to wait for long every time I go to contacts?

Comment: So you want to duplicate the contacts database into your app? I feel like querying your own SQLite table will be just as slow.

Comment: That was my original idea. But as you said it would probably be just as slow, so I was looking for some other ways to speed it up. I would also need to compare contacts to the ones on server to show only those who have my app. And that would probably slow it down a lot more.

Comment: I mean, you could potentially speed it up by using an in memory database, but that would require you to remodel the entire original contacts database and would be a lot more work than just the app features you've mentioned

Comment: I know, I will probably end up spending more time working on that than I planned. :)